# issue with wordpress theme background on widescreen computers

Tags: css, wordpress, images

I am using the theme "irresistible" and I wanted to a add a picture of the person for whom I am building the site.  Normally the background CSS uses repeat, but I don't want their picture to repeat i just want it all the way on the left side

```
body.woothemes {
    background: #18191b url(images/bg.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:left top;
    color: #e9e9e9;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 18px;
}
```

http://romesmooth1.jerseygetonline.com/

It doesn't repeat in Internet Explorer, but repeats in Firefox. In both it looks fine in a normal on a 17in LCD but not on a wide screen.

Comment: Which version of Firefox? In Firefox 4 the background stretches on a widescreen window.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your CSS as `no-repeat` will prevent it from repeating in all browsers.  You may have an issue with speciificty though, i.e. another rule is overiding your background.

If the link you provided is the actual problem page, can you explain which background image we should be looking at?